# How long should I wait for the Facebook team to enable my account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

My account is disabled. I sent my passport and my birth certificate for verification.

So, is there anyone here who has gone through this and knows how long a banned user should wait for a response?

It’s been a week since I sent the reactivation request. Is it because the provided information (birth certificate/passport) are not in English and Facebook needs time to translate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time required to complete the Facebook ID verification process varies. Generally it takes from 30 minutes to 1 week. In some cases there is no response from Facebook support team for the long time (It depends on why they have blocked your account.)

See this thread [Why is ID verification taking so long?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1448936355413962), top answer also said to wait for atleast one week.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. Now that i have a good idea on how the Facebook works, I want to know if I'm allowed to create a new account in case there was no response.. Because Facebook privacy terms clearly say that users who had their accounts disabled are forbidden to make new ones unless with a permission.

Comment: @user135783 In short: no. You cannot create a new account without express permission from Facebook Support.